# Combination and Permutation

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can 4 men and 5 women make up a special committee looking into safety in the workplace if 3 persons are selected and at least 1 committee member must be a woman?

I tried to do it i just cant figure out how to put restrictions into the formula of $nCr$ when 1 committee member must be a woman. As i did $9C3$ in my calculator I got 84. The answer is 80, I am trying to figure it out with restrictions

Comment: This kind of "do my homework for me" question is not welcomed here. Show us your effort if you want help.

Comment: Okay well i tried to do it i just cant figure out how to put restrictions into the formula of nCr when 1 committee member must be a woman. As i did 9C3 in my calculator I got 84. The answer is 80, I am trying to figure it out with restrictions.

Comment: That's better, I copied that to the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hint: Your calculation $C(9,3)$ just computed the number of ways of selecting 3 people from a total of 9 people. The result (84) is too high because, as you guess, that counting includes "forbidden" cases (which are they?). So, you only need to count those forbidden cases and substract that from 84.

Comment: By cases you mean the 4 men so subtract the 84-4men which is one case?

Comment: No. You need to understand what $C(9,3)=84$ is: it's the total number of possible selections of 3 people (imagine them). Of those 84 selections (say, teams) the forbidden one are those who are all men (no?). Now, how many ways are of selecting 3 mens from a total of 4 men?

Comment: 4 is the amount of ways

Comment: Yes, but you should compute that as another combination C(4,3)

Comment: So the funal solution is $C(9,3)-C(4,3)=84-4=80$

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

No need to subtract anything. Firstly you should understand that ....  Here "at least $1$ woman" is asked so you can calculate either all women or $2$ woman and $1$ men or $2$ men and one woman, i.e. $$C(5,3) + C(5,2)\cdot C(4,1) + C(5,1)\cdot C(4,2)$$

Comment: Yes, two multiplications and two additions is certainly to be preferred over a subtraction. It immediately shows that the result is positive.